# C# - How does dll references work?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, .net-assembly

I'm developing a client application which connects with a web service, in order to do that I'm using the WebClient class and the JavaScriptSerializer class for parse the requested string as a JSON.

I had to add a reference from System.Web.Extensions.dll for make the second one work, and works great BUT if I move my exe file to other computer obviously will throw me the exception that it cannot find the dll. I tried to copy the System.Web.Extensions.dll to the bin folder of my app and add the reference again, but it seems that it's not working..

What I want to do is simple, I want to put the dll referenced with the path of my exe file and then all the time I migrate the file wherever I want the program loads the dll through the relative path..

Seriously, I don't know why Microsoft didn't make something easier to handle (such as the import of jar files in java) it's very confusing, same happened to me with the wiaaut.dll before and I had to register it in the system with regsvr..

Comment: Why downvote? it's just a doubt I want to clarify..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be fine so long as the machine you're copying it to has the full version of .NET - not just a client profile. You shouldn't need to copy anything - it should just be fine to pull it from the GAC. Just make sure you've got the right version of .NET.

Comment: But usually when I run the application in a machine that doesn't have the Framework installed it says "You need to install the x version of the .NET Framework in order run this program" when I run it on the other computer it doesn't throw that, it's confusing..

Comment: Well, what you say is right, I was actually testing the app in my mother's computer, so she doesn't have any .NET Framework :P but I'll wait for my father's arrival for test it on his computer (he's developer too).. Thank's for your answer :)

Comment: @Neo: It's a matter of the client profile vs the full framework.

Comment: Right, I did some tests and yes, it was an issue of the .NET Framework version... Thank's for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if System.Web.Extensions.dll is in Global Assembly Cache of the target machine. For that, just open C:\Windows\Assembly folder (this is basically your GAC folder). If it isn't there, you need to install it.

To install it, use the following command:
gacutil /i

More on GacUtil here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c.aspx